# Angular 2 CLI Sample that works with AoT

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-cli

Can anyone please share an example that has AppModule and another module lets say HomeModule, with a lazy loading route to HomeModule and that works with Angular 2 Cli AoT compilation option.

When I try this I get error "HomeModule is not an NgModule.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this example.Angular is in progress of building few UI components using material design.Those examples are using angular cli and AOT.
https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app